# How to this dataset is working in the background?

Tags: sas

I am a beginner in SAS and wants to know how below programme is giving me first obs from sashelp.class and in log window, it is saying that data is stopped because of looping.

Can someone please explain, what is happening in the background?

```
data test;
if age<14;
set sashelp.class;
run;

proc print;
run;
```

Answer (score 2):

Excellent question!  It's important to learn how the DATA step works, and part of that is to know when it stops.

The typical way a DATA step stops is the SET statement tries to read the next record in a dataset and hits the end of the file.

Another way a step will stop is if it has a SET statement in it, and it goes one full iteration of the DATA step loop without a SET statement executing. When it stops for this reason, you get the "stopped due to looping" message.  It's basically protection against an infinite loop.

Look at your code, with some PUT statements added:

```
27   data test;
28     put "top of loop " _n_= age=;
29     if age<14;
30     set sashelp.class;
31     put "bottom of loop " _n_= age=;
32   run;

top of loop _N_=1 age=.
bottom of loop _N_=1 age=14
top of loop _N_=2 age=14
NOTE: DATA STEP stopped due to looping.
NOTE: There were 1 observations read from the data set SASHELP.CLASS.
NOTE: The data set WORK.TEST has 1 observations and 5 variables.
```

At the top of the first iteration of the loop, age=., so  `if age<14` is true.  The SET statement executes and the first record is read.  At the bottom of the loop age=14.

At the top of the second iteration of the loop (`_n_=2`), age=14 because it is automatically retained.  The subsetting IF statement is false.  Control goes to the bottom of the loop.  The DATA step sees that during the second of iteration of the loop, no records were read.  It stops, with the note that it stopped "due to looping."

If you change your subsetting IF to be AFTER the SET statement, the step will not stop due to looping, because on every iteration of the DATA step loop a record will be read.

```
33   data test;
34     put "top of loop " _n_= age=;
35     set sashelp.class;
36     if age<14;
37     put "bottom of loop " _n_= age=;
38   run;

top of loop _N_=1 age=.
top of loop _N_=2 age=14
bottom of loop _N_=2 age=13
top of loop _N_=3 age=13
bottom of loop _N_=3 age=13
top of loop _N_=4 age=13
top of loop _N_=5 age=14
top of loop _N_=6 age=14
bottom of loop _N_=6 age=12
top of loop _N_=7 age=12
bottom of loop _N_=7 age=12
top of loop _N_=8 age=12
top of loop _N_=9 age=15
bottom of loop _N_=9 age=13
top of loop _N_=10 age=13
bottom of loop _N_=10 age=12
top of loop _N_=11 age=12
bottom of loop _N_=11 age=11
top of loop _N_=12 age=11
top of loop _N_=13 age=14
bottom of loop _N_=13 age=12
top of loop _N_=14 age=12
top of loop _N_=15 age=15
top of loop _N_=16 age=16
bottom of loop _N_=16 age=12
top of loop _N_=17 age=12
top of loop _N_=18 age=15
bottom of loop _N_=18 age=11
top of loop _N_=19 age=11
top of loop _N_=20 age=15
NOTE: There were 19 observations read from the data set SASHELP.CLASS.
NOTE: The data set WORK.TEST has 10 observations and 5 variables.
```